# Is it safe to write an "encrypted" PIN on a card?

Tags: encryption, credit-card

I have a number of bank cards and I keep forgetting the PIN-codes, in particular because most of them I use rarely. I came up with an idea - for each card: add a secret PIN that I remember to the PIN of the card and write it on the card. Whenever I need it, I can just subtract the 'secret' pin.
Does this approach have any significant security vulnerabilities?

Comment: Well, if someone finds out the real pin for any one of your cards, they can calculate the secret pin and then calculate the real pins for all of your cards. Whether or not this threat is 'significant' is something you will have to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** it’s safe. Considering a couple assumptions, the risk is probably low.

The easy answer is no. Given time the encryption is vulnerable. But that isn’t your question. In this case, time to decrypt is limited and the risk reward for a bad actor are screed to easy, fast and certain payoff.

In your favor are:

- You’ll know when the cards are lost or stolen
- You’ll have ample time to notify the banks before you believe a thief can decrypt the cards
- The bank rate limits failed pin attempts
- The thief knows their time is short. Trying a bunch of atm pins isn’t the right risk for easy money.
- lowish likelihood the random numbers you Scribble are a pin
- The banks don’t trust the pin. They know many people use dumb pins like 0000 or 1212. It’s also common for close family to know their mother’s, father’s, or significant other’s pins.

Smarter people might come up with reasons it’s not safe, but I’d wager the one time every 15 years my cards go missing that I’d be protected.

So yeah, With the information we have now, it’s *probably* safe.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody mentioned in the comments, this is subject to what's called a crib-dragging attack, which occurs when you encrypt two separate messages using the same output from a stream cipher or a one-time pad.  If anyone finds out one message, they can determine all of the messages, and as a result, this isn't considered secure.

The way I handle this is to add my debit and credit cards to my password manager, which I have on my phone.  It has a field to store the PIN, and since it's encrypted by a strong password in addition to my phone having its own, independent password, this is secure.  In the event I need to use one of these cards, I just open up my phone, look at the PIN in the password manager, and then step up to the cashier.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is safe is mainly a matter of opinion. If is indeed safer than writing the clear text code on the card. But what you describe lies between the Cesar and Vigenere codes, meaning a very easy to break code: one single clear text/coded text pair is enough to break it by hand...
Said differently it seems *reasonably* safe because we think that the risk of someone being able to gather enough info to break the code is low.

But other ways exists which are not really much more complex and that rely as strong encryption. A simple password manager like the excellent Keypass (or its variations for smartphones) is with no doubt much more resistant.